# How do I get the sum of the revenue per month for the four id numbers with the highest total revenue using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was able to figure out which four source_id's have the highest total revenue, but I want to break it down further to revenue by month.

Eventually, I want to use the new dataframe to visualize monthly revenue for the top four source id's.

I was able to use a groupby to get the top total revenues, but I'm not sure what to do beyond this.

```
rev_sum = joined_data.groupby("source_id")["revenue"].sum()
top_id = rev_sum.sort_values(ascending = False).head(4)
top_id
```

```
table name: joined_data

    date     source_id  cost    revenue
0   1/17/14     PA01    10.0    40.0
1   2/17/14     PA02    15.0    25.0
2   1/7/14      PA02    40.0    25.0
3   3/25/14     PA03    10.0    35.0
4   2/30/14     PA03    15.0    35.0
5   3/22/14     PA05    20.0    30.0
6   1/17/14     PA04    10.0    60.0
7   3/22/14     PA01    30.0    40.0
8   2/7/14      PA04    50.0    30.0
9   1/14/14     PA02    30.0    25.0
10  2/13/14     PA03    40.0    30.0
    ...         ...     ...     ...
```

In the sample data above, "source_id": PA01, PA02, PA03, and PA04 had the highest total revenue.
In the end, I want a new table with a monthly breakdown that looks like this:

```
source_id    month    month_rev
PA01         Jan      10.0
             Feb      30.0
             Mar      0.0
PA02         Jan      40.0
             Feb      15.0
             Mar      0.0
PA03         Jan      0.0
             Feb      55.0
             Mar      10.0
PA04         Jan      10.0
             Feb      50.0
             Mar      0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new column with `month`:

```
df['month'] = [ar[0] for ar in df.date.str.split('/')]

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'],format='%m').dt.month_name()
```

Then create new dataframe with desired revenue:

```
result = df.groupby(['source_id', 'month']).sum()[['cost']].reset_index()
result = result.rename(columns={'cost':'month_revenue'})
```

*output*:

```
source_id   month   month_revenue
0   PA01    January     10.0
1   PA01    March       30.0
2   PA02    February    15.0
3   PA02    January     70.0
4   PA03    February    55.0
5   PA03    March       10.0
6   PA04    February    50.0
7   PA04    January     10.0
8   PA05    March       20.0
```

But there aren't zeros in empty months. Do you really need them?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])    
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['revenue'].sum().sort_values()
```

Can you try this and let me know the output. I take it that you are working with pandas dataframe.

Comment: I got an error when I ran it: "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: Added a small tweak to change the data format to allow for better grouping.